# SQLite two rowid's created when I explicitly create one

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a sqlite table and I need to keep the ids from changing when I [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) the database. The documentation says that VACUUM will not change the rowids of a table that has an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

So, I created a table with

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
  "rowid" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  "updated" DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  "description" TEXT
)
```

But that makes a table with two rowid columns. In SQLite Manager add-on for Firefox I see both, and when I try to access the result set in Java it says "ambiguous column: 'rowid'". Is there a way to explicitly create rowid or do I have to use a different name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rowid is a column of every SQLite table by default](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

> If a table has a primary key that consists of a single column, and the declared type of that column is INTEGER in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid.

Thus, your rowid column doesn't *replace* the default rowid. Your key is an *alias* for the default rowid.

Because of this, you really shouldn't name your column rowid, as it is already used, and will result in "ambiguous column" errors, as you have experienced already.

The documentation is saying that the rowid that SQLite is generating will not be changed if your table contains some INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. The PK does not need to be the rowid.

Comment: If I do that then I have to go back and change my code to use id rather then rowid. Doable but ...

Comment: Are you sure?  I remember reading in the SQLite documentation that if a row definition contained a field that is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` that SQLite would not generate its own internal rowid.  In fact, the link above is the documentation that contains that very language.

Comment: May I suggest add this part to your answer? *"If a table has a primary key that consists of a single column, and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid."* I found this part more clarifier to this case.

Comment: @dic19 Thanks, I added it to the explanation.

Comment: @scottb I was thinking the same thing. If I use the exact same sql statement but change 'rowid' to 'id' it does NOT create the rowid column. If it would, I could just create the id column and keep referencing the rowid in my code.

Comment: Actually Sqlite allways creates the column `rowid`, that's the point. For example if you create a column like this: `myID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, then `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE myID = 1` and `SELECT * from tablename WHERE tablename.rowid = 1` will be both valid statements and will retrieve the same result. Give it a try by yourself just to be sure, I already did and it worked.

Comment: @dic19 According the quote above myID would be an alias for rowid so these results would be expected. I take that to mean that 'rowid' will always refer to what ever column is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. What is not expected is that when I change the name myID to rowid, I then get two columns named rowid.

Comment: What I ended up doing was just using a different name then rowid and changing my code. Was not that bad. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: I get your point now. To be fair this behaviour is not clearly documented but is not totally unexpected. See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) quote: *You can access the ROWID of an SQLite table using one the special column names ROWID, _ROWID_, or OID. Except if you declare an ordinary table column to use one of those special names, then the use of that name will refer to the declared column not to the internal ROWID.* From here we can infer actually sqlite still creating its own `ROWID` column, regardless any user column with this name. Consequently we'll have two `rowid` columns.